# Jsoup.parse Mobile url

Tags: java, jsoup

I am new to Jsoup and I am trying to download a mobile website using Jsoup.parse().Code below works fine for a normal URL but not for mobiles.What's wrong with it ?

### Code:

```
 private static Document downloadDocument(String url, String referer, int timeout) {
    if (url.isEmpty() || url == null) {
        return null;
    }
    if (referer.isEmpty() || referer == null) {
        //default to google.
        referer = "http://www.google.com";
    }
    Document document;
    try {
        document = Jsoup.parse(new URL(url), timeout);
    } catch (IOException e) {
        //TODO - Remove System.out.println - Memory Issue.
        System.out.println("Sorry, unable to download document");
        return null;
    }
    return document;
}
```

Stack trace is as follows:

```
org.jsoup.HttpStatusException: HTTP error fetching URL. Status=403, URL=http://m.careerbuilder.com/
    at org.jsoup.helper.HttpConnection$Response.execute(HttpConnection.java:449)
    at org.jsoup.helper.HttpConnection$Response.execute(HttpConnection.java:424)
    at org.jsoup.helper.HttpConnection.execute(HttpConnection.java:178)
    at org.jsoup.helper.HttpConnection.get(HttpConnection.java:167)
    at org.jsoup.Jsoup.parse(Jsoup.java:183)
    ...
```

Comment: Can we see how you use this code? Example of url you want to parse would be also helpful. Also add `e.printStackTrace();` to see more informations about exception.

Comment: http://m.careerbuilder.com is the url I am trying to download.

Comment: This is not the cause of the error, but you should check if a variable is null before using it! e.g.: when you check if the url is empty or null, you should do this way: `if (url==null || url.isEmpty())`

Comment: yes, but in the wrong order. If "url" is null, your code will throw a null pointer exception

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The website you want to parse checks the user agent and does not accept the default one (which is **Java/jdk_version**). So you should use a "fake" user agent, like this:

```
Document html = Jsoup.connect("http://m.careerbuilder.com").userAgent("Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 6.2; Win64; x64) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/32.0.1667.0 Safari/537.36").get();
System.out.println(html);
```

Where **Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 6.2; Win64; x64) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/32.0.1667.0 Safari/537.36** is the user agent of Chrome 32.0.1667.0